# Como passar dados a uma nova linha criada por javascript

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

Estou criando uma função para salvar um formulario diretamente em uma tabela, as linhas da tabela contem uma função onclick que os leva a função em javascript

```js
function xpto() {
    if (linha == null) {
        var linha1 = document.getElementById("tabela").insertRow(-1);
        linha1.insertCell(0).innerHTML = document.getElementById("oT").value;
        linha1.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("tColeta").value;
        linha1.insertCell(2).innerHTML = document.getElementById("tEntrega").value;
        linha1.insertCell(3).innerHTML = document.getElementById("pEntrega").value;
        linha1.insertCell(4).innerHTML = document.getElementById("trans").value;
        linha1.insertCell(5).innerHTML = document.getElementById("mod").value;

    } else {
        linha.cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("oT").value;
        linha.cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("tColeta").value;
        linha.cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("tEntrega").value;
        linha.cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("pEntrega").value;
        linha.cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("trans").value;
        linha.cells[5].innerHTML = document.getElementById("mod").value;


    }
    linha = null;
    mostrarTabela();
}
```

como insiro atribulos na nova linha criada pela opção salvar, no caso tenho que inserir o efeito de html `onclick="editar(this)";`

```js
var linha1 = document.getElementById("tabela").insertRow (-1);
```

Comment: A tua pergunta ainda não está clara para mim. Podes juntar o HTML e o resto do código para vermos um exemplo a funcionar?

Comment: Sérgio está a ver a função xpto(), então acompanha comigo tentarei deixar claro, if (linha == null) {
        var linha1 = document.getElementById("tabela").insertRow(-1);, sabe esse insert row(-1) ele insere uma nova linha só que sem nenhuma propriedade, preciso passar a essa nova linha criada <tr> um evento onclick="editar" ou uma class="efeito", para a linha ficar de acordo com as outras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dessa forma acredito que funcione:

```
var linha1 = document.getElementById("tabela").insertRow (-1);
linha.setAttribute('class', 'row');
linha.setAttribute('onclick','editar(this)');
```

Se quiser colocar em uma coluna específica, você pode criar o elemento nesse caso coloquei um anchor mesmo, mas pode ser um span ou o que você quiser:

```
cell = linha.insertCell(index);
elemA = document.createElement('a');
elemA.setAttribute('href', '#');    
elemA.setAttribute('onclick','editar(this)');
elemA.setAttribute('title', 'Alterar');
elemA.innerHTML ="<img src='imagens/editar.jpg' name='editar' id='id' class='atualizar'>";  
cell.appendChild(elemA);
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que estava querendo, obrigado, ajudou muito mesmo.